# Laravell Put Request not Supported

Tags: php, laravel

i'm writing a Laravell page where i update the data inside my DB. And i recive this error:

> [The PUT method is not supported for route listings. Supported methods: POST.]([Laravel error tracking – Flare](https://flareapp.io/share/47qa3YA7#F3))

here my code

edit.blade.php: where i take my data

```php
<x-layout>
    <x-card class="p-10 max-w-lg mx-auto mt-24">
      <header class="text-center">
        <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold uppercase mb-1">Edit Gig</h2>
        <p class="mb-4">Edit: {{$listing->title}}</p>
      </header>

      <form method="POST" action="/listings/{{$listing->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="company" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Company Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="company"
            value="{{$listing->company}}" />

          @error('company')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="title" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Job Title</label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="title"
            placeholder="Example: Senior Laravel Developer" value="{{$listing->title}}" />

          @error('title')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="location" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">Job Location</label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="location"
            placeholder="Example: Remote, Boston MA, etc" value="{{$listing->location}}" />

          @error('location')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="email" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
            Contact Email
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="email" value="{{$listing->email}}" />

          @error('email')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="website" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
            Website/Application URL
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="website"
            value="{{$listing->website}}" />

          @error('website')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="tags" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
            Tags (Comma Separated)
          </label>
          <input type="text" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="tags"
            placeholder="Example: Laravel, Backend, Postgres, etc" value="{{$listing->tags}}" />

          @error('tags')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="logo" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
            Company Logo
          </label>
          <input type="file" class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="logo" />

          <img class="w-48 mr-6 mb-6"
            src="{{$listing->logo ? asset('storage/' . $listing->logo) : asset('/images/no-image.png')}}" alt="" />

          @error('logo')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <label for="description" class="inline-block text-lg mb-2">
            Job Description
          </label>
          <textarea class="border border-gray-200 rounded p-2 w-full" name="description" rows="10"
            placeholder="Include tasks, requirements, salary, etc">{{$listing->description}}</textarea>

          @error('description')
          <p class="text-red-500 text-xs mt-1">{{$message}}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-6">
          <button class="bg-laravel text-white rounded py-2 px-4 hover:bg-black">
            Update Gig
          </button>

          <a href="/" class="text-black ml-4"> Back </a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </x-card>
  </x-layout>
```

my routes

```php
// Show Edit Form
Route::get('/listings/{listing}/edit', [ListingController::class, 'edit']);

// Update Listing
Route::put('/listings/{listing}', [ListingController::class, 'update']);

//Single listing
Route::get('/listings/{listing}',[ListingController::class,'show']);
```

My ListingController

```php
    // Update Listing Data
    public function update(Request $request, Listing $listing) {

        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'company' => ['required'],
            'location' => 'required',
            'website' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'tags' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('logo')) {
            $formFields['logo'] = $request->file('logo')->store('logos', 'public');
        }

        $listing->update($formFields);

        return back()->with('message', 'Listing updated successfully!');
    }
```

can u help me? pls :cry:

i tried changing the type of request from the web.php but nothing changed. I even tried to remove the @method('put') from the edit.blade file but nothing changed plsss help me

Comment: It looks like you're missing the hidden `_method` input as part of the `put` handling? See: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question includes:

```
@method('PUT')
```

And:

```
Route::put('/listings/{listing}', [ListingController::class, 'update']);
```

Ensure that you did **not** in one of your tries change that.

Then clear cache, like:

```
composer dump-autoload --no-scripts --no-interaction
php artisan config:clear
composer run post-autoload-dump --verbose --no-interaction
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```